# API Manager throws error "Connection closed by target host before receiving the request"

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager, api-manager

I am trying out WSO2 api manager.

The sample api I am using is:

```
http://www.thomas-bayer.com/sqlrest/CUSTOMER
```

The hosted api url is

```
https://localhost:8243/customer/1.0.0/1
```

When I invoke the internal url, I see following headers in outbound message

```
GET http://www.thomas-bayer.com/sqlrest/CUSTOMER/1 HTTP/1.1 
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
Host: www.thomas-bayer.com
Connection: Keep-Alive
User-Agent: Synapse-PT-HttpComponents-NIO
```

However, I get following message

> Connection closed by target host before receiving the request

If I access the url (http://www.thomas-bayer.com/sqlrest/CUSTOMER/1) directly, it works.

Any idea why this might be happening?

Comment: @Tshepang was wondering if you figured this out.. or if someone else did..

Comment: @wajidmehraj I only edited the Question; I have no familiarity with the subject.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the way you are defining URL pattern is incorrect in API Manager Publisher while publishing the API.

This is how I managed to do it,

- Create two GET methods with URL pattern as follows
- /{id} - This works as a path parameter therefore when calling the API you can pass the customer ID after the "/"
- /*    - This gives the list of customers
- Use "http://www.thomas-bayer.com/sqlrest/CUSTOMER" as your production Endpoint

After defining above way,

- You can call the API with "h ttps://localhost:8243/customer/1.0.0" which gives the list of customers
- To view a specific customer details you can use the endpoint as "https://localhost:8243/customer/1.0.0/1" which works as a path parameter